# arrange items dynamically in two columns in isotope js

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I have an isotope container. I want to have two columns (divs) inside the container, then feed items dynamically from a database call into those columns. Not sure how to do this. What I have below adds items to the container, but I can't seem to get the items into divs inside the container. I want two divs/columns side by side.

HTML

```
<div class="lawmakers">

        <!-- HOUSE -->
        <div class="left house">
            <h2>House</h2>


        </div><!-- End House -->

        <!-- Senate -->
        <div class="right senate">
            <h2>Senate</h2>


        </div><!-- End Senate -->

    </div><!-- END HOUSE/SENATE REPS -->
```

jquery

```
    var $container = $('.lawmakers'),
      filters = {};

      $container.isotope({
        itemSelector : '.info'
      });


      var iso = $container.data('isotope');
      $container.isotope( 'reveal', iso.items );

    ...
$.post("php/getData.php", function(data){ 
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

            for (var i=0; i< obj.length; i++) {
            //obtain data such as partyAbbrev and county
    var $newItems = $('<div class="info ' + partyAbbrev + ' ' + county + '">\
                    </div>');


        }
        $('.lawmakers').isotope( 'insert', $newItems );
});
```

Comment: What have you tried to put them into the `.left.house` and `.right.senate` divs ? I mean, how can you know which "entry" goes into one or the other column ?

Comment: Yes, but then isotope filters and animations don't work.

Comment: Maybe you should provide your JSON result.

Comment: If I say $('.lawmakers .senate').isotope( 'insert', $newItems ); then I get the message "cannot call methods on isotope prior to initialization; attempted to call 'insert'"

Comment: It's too long. Problem is not in the json, it's getting the items into the isotope container.

Comment: because of your `$container` declaration. You have to change it to `$('.lawmakers .senate')` also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare and initialize your containers :

```
var $houseContainer = $('.lawmakers .house');
var $senateContainer = $('.lawmakers .senate');

$houseContainer.isotope({
    itemSelector : '.info'
});
$senateContainer.isotope({
    itemSelector : '.info'
});

...

$houseContainer.isotope('insert', $newItems /* or whatever */);
$senateContainer.isotope('insert', $newItems /* or whatever */);
```

As a side note, you can replace your `$.post` :

```
$.post("php/getData.php", function(data){ 
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
});
```

With [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) :

```
$.getJSON("php/getData.php", function(obj) {
});
```